# Display a different row color according with the text written on the cell

Tags: php, html, css, html-table

Hi am struggling with this:

I have a PHP snippet that I want to apply to my web page in order to change table row color if the text is equivalent to "PRIORITY" or "SUPPORT". I need help to implement the php into the HTML part of the tables.

SNIPPET

```
<?php 
function switchColor($rowValue) { 

//Define the colors first 
$color1 = '#e2e2e2'; 
$color2 = '#00ff00'; 
$color3 = '#0000ff'; 

switch ($rowValue) { 
    case 'PRIORITY': 
        echo $color1; 
        break; 
    case 'ADVISORY': 
        echo $color2; 
        break; 
    default: 
        echo $color3; 
       } 
      } 

    ?>
```

I NEED TO IMPLEMENT IN THIS TABLE

```
<tr class="tablerow<?php echo $count; ?>">
                <td style="background-color: #92c38e; text-align: 
center;">
                    <span style="font-size: medium;"><?php print 
strip_tags($category_name) ?></span>
                </td>
                <td style="background-color: #92c38e; text-align: 
center;">
                    <?php foreach($category as $num=>$categor){
                        if($num != sizeof($category)-1){
                        ?>
                        <span style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 
medium;" data-id="<?php echo $categor['item_id']; ?>"><?php print 
strip_tags($categor['item_name']); ?></span>,&nbsp
                        <?php } else {?>
                        <span style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 
medium;" data-id="<?php echo $categor['item_id']; ?>"><?php print 
strip_tags($categor['item_name']); ?></span>
                    <?php } } ?>
                </td>
<!--THIS IS THE COLUMN WHERE THE CELL SHOULD CHANGE COLOR WHEN THE TEXT IS EQUIVALENT TO THE WORDS "PRIORITY OR ADVISORY-->
                <td style="background-color: #92c38e; text-align: 
center;">
                    <span style="color: #ffffff; font-size: medium;">
<?php print strip_tags($category[0]['status']); ?></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

I need help into formulating the correct PHP syntax in order to apply the `switchColor` function from the snippet.

Comment: you can also use bootstrap's table classes and assign on row level

Comment: What is going to be passed to the $rowValue variable? is it this: <?php print strip_tags($category[0]['status']); ?>?

Comment: @Varin yes it is correct

Comment: Guys, this is not a duplicate, this is a question involving code generated from server-side, while the other question, marked as the duplicate of this one is about a client-side function. It is obvious that both questions are about the same PHP/Wordpress project, but they are completely different projects, I kindly ask you to pay more attention before you close a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
<td style="background-color: #92c38e; text-align: 
center;">
```

you already have the structure, you just need the effective `background-color` value:

```
<td style="background-color: <?php echo switchColor(strip_tags($category[0]['status'])); ?>; text-align: 
center;">
```

At least this is the solution if I understood well your question. If not, let me know.

Comment: This does change the color but unfortunately now the text from the cell is gone

Comment: @Diego because you have removed the span you had inside the td. I was describing only the td, the only change you need compared to your initial question is to change the #92c38e in your background-color to <?php echo switchColor(strip_tags($category[0]['status'])); ?>

Comment: YOU ARE THE WINNER..! Not only t works just fine but also it was the easiest solution of all..!

Comment: Many Thanks for all your patience and extraordinary help, you have ended my agony.

Comment: @Diego I was happy to help. If this answer solved your problem, then you might consider accepting it. Anyway, I am happy I could contribute to improve your day and to reduce frustrations.

Comment: definitely yes I have marked the answer as a yes. Did I do it right?

Comment: @Diego yes, you did, thank you.

Comment: Excellent..Thank you again..!

Answer (score 1):

You can set the table row color like:

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr bgcolor="#FF0000">
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In your case call the function instead of passing the hard code color value like:

```
<tr bgcolor="<?php switchColor('variable that contains the value passed here') ?>">
```

Comment: While this question is solved, I wanted to thank you for taking the time and answering my call.

Answer (score 0):

You can make class for your row table and don't use function on php. For example

```
<tr class="tablerow<?php echo $count; ?> row_<? echo $rowValue; ?>"></tr>
```

And add this class to CSS.

Comment: can you elaborate your CSS example I don't see the color reference

Comment: I have found and easy solution by following the suggestion from Lajos Arpad, I still wanted to thank you fore taking the time and answering my distress call.

Comment: That's easy solution, but you should ceparate your HTML and CSS

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify it by using CSS. Just have a CSS class for each type of priority, and you will just have to add the good class to the good row.

```css
tr {background:yellow ; }
tr.PRIORITY { background:red; }
tr.ADVISORY { background:blue ; }


table { width:100% ; }
```

```html
Here is an example without PHP just to see how it works and how it should be rendered in html source
<table>
  <tr class="PRIORITY"><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr class="ADVISORY"><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr class=""><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr class=""><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
</table>

<hr />

Here is what you have to do in php : just "echo" your priority level in class of your tr and that's it.
<table>
  <?php foreach ( $rows as $row ) { ?>
  <tr class="tablerow<?php echo $count; ?> <?php echo $row['YourVarWithPriority'] ; ?>"><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: The asker asked for the syntax to enter things into a style tag's background-color value. He is clearly a beginner, let's address the question and give him the syntax as well.

Comment: @Pierre Granger The cells are dynamically populated with content, I don't have a way to know which cell will have the word "PRIORITY" in it. I am not sure I understand your answer.

Comment: Forget the first part, it's an example without php. What you need is the second part. You have "PRIORITY" or "ADVISORY" stored in your row right ? like $row['priority-type'] or something ? So you just dynamically write in in classname and that's it.

Comment: @Pierre Granger, first of all many thanks for trying to help me. My reference code is the one above, the text for the cells in the table,  is fetched from PHP and I do not store it in a static way. Unfortunately your explanation was difficult to understand for me. The solution offered by Lajos Arpad did actually work, so the cells are now changing background color when the word "PRIORITY" appears in them, the only problem I have right now is that the text has gone, so the PHP sintax has to be reviewed as so to display the text and I would be fine.

Comment: @Pierre Granger I have followed the solution from Lajos Arpad and it actually worked fine, however I wanted to thank you for taking the time and answering my call.

Comment: No problem glad it works for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to use this particular function, I'd do this:

```
<?php 
function switchColor($rowValue) { 

//Define the colors first 
$color1 = '#e2e2e2'; 
$color2 = '#00ff00'; 
$color3 = '#0000ff'; 

switch ($rowValue) { 
    case 'PRIORITY': ?>
        <td style="background-color: <?php echo $color1?>" text-align: center;">
            <span style="color: #ffffff; font-size: medium;"><?php echo $rowValue?>    
            </span>
        </td>
        <?php
        break; 
    case 'ADVISORY': ?>
        <td style="background-color: <?php echo $color2?>" text-align: center;">
            <span style="color: #ffffff; font-size: medium;"><?php echo $rowValue?>    
            </span>
        </td>
        <?php 
        break; 
    default: ?>
        <td style="background-color: <?php echo $color3?>" text-align: center;">
            <span style="color: #ffffff; font-size: medium;"><?php echo $rowValue?>    
            </span>
        </td>
        <?php 
       } 
      } 
?>
```

And then in the HTML :

```
<tr class="tablerow<?php echo $count; ?>">
                <td style="background-color: #92c38e; text-align: 
center;">
                    <span style="font-size: medium;"><?php print 
strip_tags($category_name) ?></span>
                </td>
                <td style="background-color: #92c38e; text-align: 
center;">
                    <?php foreach($category as $num=>$categor){
                        if($num != sizeof($category)-1){
                        ?>
                        <span style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 
medium;" data-id="<?php echo $categor['item_id']; ?>"><?php print 
strip_tags($categor['item_name']); ?></span>,&nbsp
                        <?php } else {?>
                        <span style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 
medium;" data-id="<?php echo $categor['item_id']; ?>"><?php print 
strip_tags($categor['item_name']); ?></span>
                    <?php } } ?>
                </td>
<!--THIS IS THE COLUMN WHERE THE CELL SHOULD CHANGE COLOR WHEN THE TEXT IS EQUIVALENT TO THE WORDS "PRIORITY OR ADVISORY-->
                <?php switchColor(strip_tags($category[0]['status']);)?>
```

Comment: This solution refactors a well separated function and includes HTML generation into it. As a result, this answer cannot be advised to users. If you want to improve the structure of the code, it is a good approach, but you did it in the wrong way. Leave switchColor as it is to allow later usage and do not dedicate it for this specific use-case. Instead, write a HTML generating function, which will take the color as a parameter and echoes that color (the only difference) at the appropriate place. Then echo generateColoredTag(switchColor(strip_tags($category[0]['status'])));